# NameError: name 'pip3' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, package

I'm using Python 3 on Jupyter Notebooks. I've tried using pip3 to install packages which appears to work until I try importing such package, when I usually get a module not found error. For some reason, I get no such module not found error when I used pip to install packages. This is strange since both pip and pip3 are in the same folder on my computer.

To try to diagnose this problem. I just typed pip in a Jupyter cell and got the following output.

```
Usage:   
  /Users/name/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip <command> [options]

Commands:
  install                     Install packages.
  download                    Download packages.
  uninstall                   Uninstall packages.
  freeze                      Output installed packages in requirements format.
  list                        List installed packages.

etc.

General Options:
  -h, --help                  Show help.
  --isolated                  Run pip in an isolated mode, ignoring
                              environment variables and user configuration.
  -v, --verbose               Give more output. Option is additive, and can be
                              used up to 3 times.
  -V, --version               Show version and exit.
  -q, --quiet                 Give less output. Option is additive, and can be
                              used up to 3 times (corresponding to WARNING,
                              ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).
etc.
```

However, when I did the same for pip3, this is what I got

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-896908e64b2d> in <module>
----> 1 pip3

NameError: name 'pip3' is not defined
```

This is strange to me as I can clearly install packages using pip and pip3 from Jupyter notebooks and they are installed to the same location. However, I then subsequently am not able to import packages originally installed using pip3

Comment: do you have `pip` location in PATH?

Comment: I followed your advice and tried to check but when I enter echo $PYTHONPATH in my terminal to check what the existing PATH is, nothing pops up. There literally is no output

Comment: Since you are using Anaconda, you'd use conda/mamba and only resort to using `pip` for packages that aren't at Ancaconda/cond-forge, etc..`%conda install <package_name>` inside your notebook to install to the same environment backing the notebook kernel will work as an option. Running `%pip install <package_name>` in Jupyter. The magic command will be used if you just put `pip` in the notebook as automagics are usually on. I would suggest you don't need to concern yourself with `pip3` inside Jupyter, just use `%pip` and let the magic handle things.

Comment: See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic commands `%pip install` and `%conda install` for Jupyter/IPython.

Comment: Thanks! Conda helps! Also using PATH to see which directories Jupyter searches through was helpful